# Function of comma in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have been furiously googling to find out what the " , " does in Visual Basic...

You can do things such as,

```
Dim result As [String], help As [String]
```

Or

```
Dim result, help As [String]
```

Both of which, are valid.

But how does the compiler treat this?

In the first example, I assume result is declared as a [String] as is help. But in the second example, is result just declared as a variant and then help is declared as [String] or are both declared as a [String]?

I have also found that the comma is only valid in declaration statements.

Please point me to the documentation if possible.

Comment: I think this is one way `VB6/VBA` differs from `VB.NET`. The statement `Dim x, y, z as Double` has a different result between the two.

Comment: Also, in `C#` you can do `string result="a", help;` but in `VB.NET` you cannot do `Dim result="a", help as String`.

Comment: You don't need the escape braces for [String] since it is the type. You need it when you do: `Dim [String] As String` - it means I want to name something that is reserved as a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking here: [Dim Statement (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx)

The way I solved this problem was search for "Dim Statement VB.NET" in Google.

Comment: Never thought of just looking up the Dim statement... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [msdn.microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx)...

If you declare more than one variable with one As clause, you cannot supply an initializer for that group of variables.
You can specify different data types for different variables by using a separate As clause for each variable you declare. Each variable takes the data type specified in the first As clause encountered after its variablename part.

For example...

```
 Dim lastTime, nextTime, allTimes() As Date 'This is valid...
```